# Will incense affect other players near me?

Tags: pokemon-go

> Incense: "Incense with a mysterious fragrance that lures wild Pokémon
>   to your location for 30 minutes."

I have observed that if a Pokémon appears for me at a given time and location it will also appear for others nearby. Does this mean that if one person in a group uses incense that it will help others in the group as well?

Comment: Saw this topic out of the corner of my eye and was rather dissappointed that it didn't actually read "Will Pokemon go insane..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regular incense does not affect other players.
You can use a Lure Module and attach it to a PokéStop. It *does* affect other players.

> Lure modules attract Pokemon to the PokéStop it was activated on.
> These Pokemon are visible to you and everyone else near the PokéStop.

[image: Lure module]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. How do I attach an incense to a Pokespot ? Is that the same incense or do we need any other special Incense for Pokespots? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It is not, it's a purple looking thing, I can't quite recall the name. It's available in the poke shop and maybe for free at later levels.

Comment: Got it with little Google. I think you are talking about `Lure Module` http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Lure_Module

Comment: As I understand it, incense per se does not affect other players, but, like all pokemon spawns, other players will see the pokemon that spawn because of it.

Comment: Can we get some more details/references on the incense in this answer? Its mostly about lures and contradicts what I've read elsewhere... including the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Incense only works for the player who uses the Incense, others don't see the pokemons spawned by it. A Lure module however will spawn pokemon at a poke stop that all players will see.

Answer (score 0):

I often walk with friends and we use incense all the time, and we do all see the same (amount) of pokémon appear.

Comment: Do you use it all at the same time or 1 at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Works on self only. Any extra Pokemon you encounter if you didn't use an incense yourself is purely coincidental .

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Sorry but this answer doesn't differ from the accepted one.

Answer (score -8):

Usually with those If another nearby player is using it you are able to use it as well.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.